# Create insert-only table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Is there an SQL statement to create an insert-only table in PostgreSQL (v9.5); in other words, with write permissions it is possible to add rows, but not possible to change existing rows?

```
CREATE TABLE public.newtable
```

Tables are only updated with `INSERT` statements, not using `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements.

Comment: don't know about the table itself, but you could always just create a user that only has insert privs on that table, which would deny update/delete

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This command will allow you to [REVOKE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-revoke.html) any privileges you may have [GRANT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html)ed:

```
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE newtable FROM PUBLIC;
```

Then, you'll want to GRANT the INSERT privilege to the role(s) that need to insert data:

```
GRANT INSERT ON TABLE newtable TO role;
```

Despite the above, the database/[schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html) owner can still do whatever he or she would like. So, you should consider creating a specific role for the purpose.